# Чем осложнено предложение.

Tags: синтаксис

Ведь человеческий фермент универсален и позволяет противостоять тринадцати различным химикатам, способным нанести не поправимый ущерб живому организму.

Answer (score 1):

А помимо  обособленного определения предложение делают осложненным однородные сказуемые "универсален" и "позволяет противостоять".

Answer (score 0):

Предложение осложнено обособленным определением, выраженным прилагательным с зависимыми словами. (P.S.Cлово "непоправимый" пишется слитно)

Answer (score 0):

Ведь человеческий фермент универсален и позволяет противостоять тринадцати различным химикатам, способным нанести не поправимый ущерб живому организму. Предложение простое. Осложнено однородными сказуемыми: составным именным (универсален) и составным глагольным (позволяет противостоять). Кроме того, осложнено обособленным согласованным определением, выраженным  прилагательным с зависимыми словами (способным нанести непоправимый ущерб организму). Непоправимый пишем слитно, потому что это отглагольное прилагательное: отсутствуют слова с приставкой НИ, слова  ВОВСЕ, ОТНЮДЬ, ДАЛЕКО и нет противопоставления с союзом а.